# Selenium WebDriverWait TimeoutException When Trying to Fetch Data into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a Python script that involves fetching data from a webpage and storing it in a pandas DataFrame. However, I'm encountering an issue where the DataFrame is returning as null. I'm unable to fetch the records as expected.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def extract_data_from_table(table):
    countries = []
    regions_states = []
    start_dates = []
    end_dates = []

    if table is not None:
        for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            columns = row.find_all('td')

            if len(columns) >= 4:
                countries.append(columns[0].text.strip())
                regions_states.append(columns[1].text.strip())
                start_dates.append(columns[2].text.strip())
                end_dates.append(columns[3].text.strip())

        return pd.DataFrame({
            'Country': countries,
            'Regions/States': regions_states,
            'DST Start Date': start_dates,
            'DST End Date': end_dates
        }) 
    else:
        return None

url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2023.html"

# Create an instance of Chrome Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

# Set up a WebDriverWait that will wait up to 1000 seconds for the table to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000)

driver.get(url)

# Wait for the table to appear
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'table table--inner-borders-all table--left table--striped table--hover')))

# Get the page source and parse it with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_='table table--inner-borders-all table--left table--striped table--hover')

df = extract_data_from_table(table)

driver.quit()

if df is not None:
    print(df)
```

When I run this code, I expect to see a DataFrame filled with the records I'm trying to fetch. However, what I'm getting instead is a null DataFrame. I've tried to debug this issue by checking the source of the records and ensuring that the data is indeed there, but I'm still unable to populate the DataFrame.

Here's the error message I'm receiving:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/rajeevranjanpandey/test.py", line 51, in <module> wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'table table--inner-borders-all table--left table--striped table--hover'))) File "/Users/rajeevranjanpandey/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)`

I'm relatively new to Python, Selenium, and pandas, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone suggest what might be the issue here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Here are the steps I've taken to try to solve this problem:

- Checked the URL to ensure it's correct and the webpage is accessible.
- Verified that the table I'm trying to scrape exists on the webpage.
- Checked the class name of the table in the webpage's HTML to ensure it matches the one in my code.
- Increased the WebDriverWait timeout to see if the table just needed more time to load.

Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the same issue. I'm relatively new to Python, Selenium, and pandas, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone suggest what might be the issue here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution as per your parsing logic.

Without using **Selenium** (with **requests+BeautifulSoup**):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

def extract_data_from_table(table):
    countries = []
    regions_states = []
    start_dates = []
    end_dates = []
    prev_country = None
    if table:
        for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
            try:
                country_col = row.find('th').text.strip()
                prev_country = country_col
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            other_col = row.find_all('td')
            if len(other_col) > 2:
                countries.append(prev_country)
                regions_states.append(other_col[0].text.strip())
                start_dates.append(other_col[1].text.strip())
                end_dates.append(other_col[2].text.strip())

        return pd.DataFrame({
            'Country': countries,
            'Regions/States': regions_states,
            'DST Start Date': start_dates,
            'DST End Date': end_dates
        })
    else:
        return None

data = requests.get('https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2023.html', headers={"Accept-Language": "en"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_='table table--inner-borders-all table--left table--striped table--hover')
df = extract_data_from_table(table)

if df is not None:
    print(df)
```

output:

```
                      Country                                     Regions/States         DST Start Date            DST End Date
0               Åland Islands                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
1                     Albania                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
2                     Andorra                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
3                  Antarctica                                     Some locations   Sunday, 24 September         Sunday, 2 April
4                  Antarctica                                      Troll Station       Sunday, 19 March      Sunday, 29 October
5                   Australia                                     Most locations      Sunday, 1 October         Sunday, 2 April
6                   Australia                                   Lord Howe Island      Sunday, 1 October         Sunday, 2 April
7                     Austria                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
8                     Belgium                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
9                     Bermuda                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
10     Bosnia and Herzegovina                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
11                   Bulgaria                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
12                     Canada                                     Most locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
13                      Chile                                     Most locations    Sunday, 3 September         Sunday, 2 April
14                      Chile                                      Easter Island  Saturday, 2 September       Saturday, 1 April
15                    Croatia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
16                       Cuba                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
17                     Cyprus                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
18                    Czechia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
19                    Denmark                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
20                      Egypt                                      All locations       Friday, 28 April      Friday, 27 October
21                    Estonia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
22              Faroe Islands                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
23                       Fiji                                      All locations    Sunday, 12 November  Does not end this year
24                    Finland                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
25                     France                                     Most locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
26                    Germany                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
27                  Gibraltar                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
28                     Greece                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
29                  Greenland                                     Most locations     Saturday, 25 March    Saturday, 28 October
30                  Greenland                                   Ittoqqortoormiit       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
31                  Greenland                                     Thule Air Base       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
32                   Guernsey                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
33                      Haiti                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
34                    Hungary                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
35                    Ireland                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
36                Isle of Man                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
37                     Israel                                      All locations       Friday, 24 March      Sunday, 29 October
38                      Italy                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
39                     Jersey                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
40                     Kosovo                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
41                     Latvia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
42                    Lebanon                                      All locations     Thursday, 30 March      Sunday, 29 October
43              Liechtenstein                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
44                  Lithuania                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
45                 Luxembourg                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
46                      Malta                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
47                     Mexico  Baja California, much of Chihuahua, much of Ta...       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
48                    Moldova                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
49                     Monaco                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
50                 Montenegro                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
51                    Morocco                                      All locations       Sunday, 23 April        Sunday, 19 March
52                Netherlands                                     Most locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
53                New Zealand                                      All locations   Sunday, 24 September         Sunday, 2 April
54             Norfolk Island                                      All locations      Sunday, 1 October         Sunday, 2 April
55            North Macedonia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
56                     Norway                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
57                  Palestine                                      All locations     Saturday, 29 April    Saturday, 28 October
58                   Paraguay                                      All locations      Sunday, 1 October        Sunday, 26 March
59                     Poland                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
60                   Portugal                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
61                    Romania                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
62  Saint Pierre and Miquelon                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
63                 San Marino                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
64                     Serbia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
65                   Slovakia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
66                   Slovenia                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
67                      Spain                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
68                     Sweden                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
69                Switzerland                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
70                The Bahamas                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
71   Turks and Caicos Islands                                      All locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
72                    Ukraine                                     Most locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
73             United Kingdom                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
74              United States                                     Most locations       Sunday, 12 March      Sunday, 5 November
75    Vatican City (Holy See)                                      All locations       Sunday, 26 March      Sunday, 29 October
76             Western Sahara                                      All locations       Sunday, 23 April        Sunday, 19 March
```

To make sure that the result is in English, pass the `headers` along with requests. `headers={"Accept-Language": "en"}`

[UPDATE]: To answer your 2nd question in the comment below:

```py
# to make the URL dynamic sensing the current year
from datetime import datetime

data = requests.get(f'https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/{datetime.now().year}.html', headers={"Accept-Language": "en"})
```

you can simply pass `datetime.now().year` to get the year at present. if you run it next year, the URL will be `https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2024.html` and so on.

Comment: This is the perfect example of what I've been looking for. Could you please elaborate on these two points for me?
1. Why is it showing up in the Malay language even though I have English selected as my Locale/Configure Display Language? Why it is behaving differently in different location.
2. How can I make this code dynamic for each year? The URL currently points to the Data for 2023, how can I ensure that it will change to 2024 next year without requiring any manual intervention?

Comment: @RajeevPandey, I've added the update to the answer above to address your 2nd point

Answer (score 0):

`By.CLASS_NAME` only accept single class value not the multiple class values,
Instead use `By.CSS_SELECTOR`

//Wait for the table to appear

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table.table--inner-borders-all.table--left.table--striped.table--hover')))
```

//Get the html of the table element

```
tableContent=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table.table--inner-borders-all.table--left.table--striped.table--hover'))).get_attribute("outerHtml")
```

//Use in built method to get the data frame, no need to use soup and parsing

```
df=pd.read_html(tableContent)[0]
print(df)
```

---

Alternatively you can just use two lines of code, selenium even doesn't need.

```
df=pd.read_html("https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2023.html")
print(df[0])
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this Tip . This does solve the issue.
I have one question though 
               Country                                   Regions/States  DST Start Date     DST End Date
0          Afghanistan                                    All locations  No DST in 2023   No DST in 2023
1        Åland Islands                                    All locations     Ahad 26 Mac  Ahad 29 Oktober

When I run this code, I am seeing Incomplete Value for Time start and Time End /For example Sunday, 26 March is appearing Ahad 26 Mac and October is coming as Oktober. Whats the reason behind this ?

Comment: I have no idea. However when I ran the code I don't see different values.

Comment: I don't know what the reason for this weird behavior

                              Country                                     Regions/States        DST Start Date            DST End Date
0                         Afghanistan                                      All locations        No DST in 2023          No DST in 2023
1                       Åland Islands                                      All locations           Ahad 26 Mac         Ahad 29 Oktober
2                             Albania                                      All locations           Ahad 26 Mac         Ahad 29 Oktober